# CSV Helper saying item does not exist when it does

Tags: c#, csvhelper

I am trying to use csv helper libary to parse my csv. But I am having an issue it says that the itemcode does not exist when its there in the file.

```
    // Adding stock item code 
Sage.Accounting.Stock.StockItem stockItem = new Sage.Accounting.Stock.StockItem();

string line = null;
public void ImportCsv(string filename)
{
         TextReader reader = File.OpenText(filename);



    var csv = new CsvReader(reader);
        csv.Configuration.HasHeaderRecord = true;
        csv.Read();
        // Dynamic
      // Using anonymous type for the class definition
        var anonymousTypeDefinition = new
        {
            Itemcode = string.Empty,
            Barcode = string.Empty 
        };
        var records = csv.GetRecords(anonymousTypeDefinition);


 }
```

This is the csv structure

"Itemcode","Barcode","description"

"P4S100001","303300054486","Test Product"

This is my first time using the csvhelper as showing here at https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/

Comment: Does `GetRecord()` work?  It looks like you've mixed the "get single record" and "read all records" examples together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are better off creating a strongly typed model to hold the data if one does not already exist

```
public class Item {
    public string Itemcode { get; set; }
    public string Barcode { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
}
```

and using [`GetRecords<T>()`](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/reading#getting-all-records) to read the records by type

```
TextReader reader = File.OpenText(filename);
var csv = new CsvReader(reader);
var records = csv.GetRecords<Item>();
```

Comment: I think his issue is the quotes in the headers. But complicity agree on making a class also a mapping for Pascal case on description would be good as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your GetRecords function needs a type specifier like so:

```
var records = csv.GetRecords<type>();
```

Also you may want to put csv.Read() in a while loop depending on your need.

Answer (score 0):

Since all your values have quotes you need to specify it in the config. Working with quotes in csvHelper is frustrating. if not all if the values have quotes there are ways to handle that as well but not as nicely as this

```
 var csv = new CsvReader(reader,new CsvHelper.Configuration.Configuration
            {
                HasHeaderRecord = true,
                QuoteAllFields = true
            });


            var anonymousTypeDefinition = new
            {
                Itemcode = string.Empty,
                Barcode = string.Empty
            };
            var records = csv.GetRecords(anonymousTypeDefinition);
```